# sp_send_dbmail is missing in sqlserver2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sp-send-dbmail, system-stored-procedures

I am unable to find the system stored procedure sp_send_dbmail,
which should be under System Databases -> msdb.

msdb.[dbo].sp_send_dbmail .

But it's missing under the location where it should be.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Configuration for mail was not enabled which was the reason i couldn't find sp_send_dbmail in system stored procedures.

Fix:

server->Database->Management->Database Mail(Rt click)->Configure Database Mail->Next->First Option and Next

It will ask you to enable the configuration for database mail and click ok.

[image]